# Save file in Visual Studio 2015 package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working on my first `Visual Studio` extension. I managed to setup event listener when a file is saved and modify another file using `DocData` on this way:

```
var docData = new DocData(this, fileName);
var editorAdaptersFactoryService = (this.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel).GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
var textBuffer = editorAdaptersFactoryService.GetDataBuffer(docData.Buffer);
textBuffer.Replace(new Span(0, textBuffer.CurrentSnapshot.Length), content);
```

The problem here is that after I modify this new file I have to save it but I couldn't find any examples about how to save a file. Inside my `DocumentSaved` listener I have a `EnvDTE.Document` where I can call `EnvDTE.Document.Save()` but I'm trying to save another file, I have the full path of this new file I'm trying to save. I though about iterating over all the files in the project looking for my specific file and there use the available `Save()` method in `ProjectItem`. I tried using the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435724/1335209) answer but it didn't work.

Any guidance on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the full Path you could try

```
ProjectItem DTE.Solution.FindProjectItem("Fullpath")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.findprojectitem.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! :)